# Sending user to specific page from notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, bundles

I am building a android application, I have got notifications working using firebase functions and the firebase messaging service. I am currently looking at getting the notification to send the user to a specific page dependant on the notificaiton. I have started to do this by passing data across with the notification which sets an intent which is put into a pending intent which is set as a contentintent in the notification builder as in the code below.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.iconcrossroadscwhite))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconcrossroadscwhite)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);


    Intent notificationIntent = null;

    if(tag.equals("acceptBidNotification"))
    {
       notificationIntent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, SplashScreen.class);
       notificationIntent.putExtra("menuFragment", "myJobsFragment");
       notificationIntent.putExtra("tabView", "Active");
    }
    else if(tag.equals("newBidNotification"))
    {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, SplashScreen.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("menuFragment", "myAdvertsFragment");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("tabView", "Pending");
    }
    else if(tag.equals("jobCompletedNotification"))
    {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, SplashScreen.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("menuFragment", "myAdvertsFragment");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("tabView", "Completed");
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



    notificationManager.notify(count, notificationBuilder.build());
    count++;
```

This then passes over to the splash screen as I found that if I passed it to my other main class that held all of the apps fragments, it was overriding it after and just running the app as normal and going to the "Find A Job" Page. I then created this method within the SplashScreen.java which checks if the bundle contains information and if it does then to send it to the specified page. However for some reason it seems to be running the splash screen before running the messaging code that will set that information. This therefore is meaning the bundle is empty or contains information which isn't the right bundle meaning the information need is null.

**SplashScreen.java**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


private GifImageView gifImageView;
private String menuFragment, tabView;
private Bundle newBundle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        menuFragment = bundle.getString("menuFragment");
        tabView = bundle.getString("tabView");
    }

    gifImageView = (GifImageView)findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);


    try{
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("crossroadssplash.gif");
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        gifImageView.setBytes(bytes);
        gifImageView.startAnimation();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {

    }

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(menuFragment != null && tabView != null)
            {
                if(menuFragment.equals("myJobsFragment"))
                {
                    newBundle = new Bundle();
                    newBundle.putString("tabView", tabView);
                    MyJobsFragment myJobsFragment = new MyJobsFragment();
                    myJobsFragment.setArguments(newBundle);
                    getFragmentTransaction().replace(R.id.content, myJobsFragment).commit();

                }
                else if(menuFragment.equals("myAdvertsFragment"))
                {
                    newBundle = new Bundle();
                    newBundle.putString("tabView", tabView);
                    MyAdvertsFragment myAdvertsFragment = new MyAdvertsFragment();
                    myAdvertsFragment.setArguments(newBundle);
                    getFragmentTransaction().replace(R.id.content, myAdvertsFragment).commit();
                }
            }
            else {
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class));
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }
    }, 7000);
}
private FragmentTransaction getFragmentTransaction()
{
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    return fragmentTransaction;
}

}
```

Any extra code can be provided if needed. Thanks

Comment: This is out of context but are you showing your Splash screen for 7 seconds? That's too much.

Comment: Yeah I know, thats an issue that I'm changing, you don't think 7 seconds is long till you are sat watching it constantly hahahaha

Comment: your app is in foreground or in background while receiving this notification?

Comment: If it is in background then procedure is different if in foreground then simple startActivity with intents will work